# Application Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

For a fun winterbreak project, I'm trying to write a tool for mac that, depending on whichever application is currently in focus, will show all the appropriate Keyboard shortcuts.  I'm still thinking about how it might work, as well as still looking around for info.  But, I'm of course wondering whether or not there is even a streamlined format for defining keyboard shortcuts on mac.  Does anyone have any light to shed here?  I'm looking for plist's on my computer, but nothing is coming up, so I'm not sure that that is the proper solution.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance, even for downvotes(:

Comment: Judging from the [FAQ](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/faq.html) on KeyCue (which does what you're describing), you're going to want to use the Accessibility API to scan the menubar for the current application.

Comment: Thats awesome.  I've been using this app for just a few days now and I love it, thinking about buying the real version.  Thanks Brian